# Understanding Java 17 Vector slowness and performance with pow operator

Tags: java, performance, vectorization, simd, java-17

I have a question relating to the pow() function in Java's 17 new Vector API feature. I'm trying to implement the black scholes formula in a vectorized manner, but I'm having difficulty in obtaining the same performance as the scalar implementation

The code is as follows:

1. I create an array of doubles (currently, just 5.0)
2. I loop over elements of that array (different looping syntax for scalar and vector)
3. I create DoubleVectors from the double arrays within and do calculations (or just calculations for scalar) I am trying to do e^(value), and I believe that is the problem

Here are some code snippets:

```
    public static double[] createArray(int arrayLength)
    {
        double[] array0 = new double[arrayLength];
        for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
        {
            array0[i] = 2.0;
        }
        return array0;
    }
```

```
    @Param({"256000"})
    int arraySize;
    public static final VectorSpecies<Double> SPECIES = DoubleVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;
    DoubleVector vectorTwo =  DoubleVector.broadcast(SPECIES,2);
    DoubleVector vectorHundred =  DoubleVector.broadcast(SPECIES,100);

    double[] scalarTwo = new double[]{2,2,2,2};
    double[] scalarHundred  = new double[]{100,100,100,100};

    @Setup
    public void Setup()
    {
        javaSIMD = new JavaSIMD();
        javaScalar = new JavaScalar();
        spotPrices = createArray(arraySize);
        timeToMaturity = createArray(arraySize);
        strikePrice = createArray(arraySize);
        interestRate = createArray(arraySize);
        volatility = createArray(arraySize);
        e = new double[arraySize];
        for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
        {
            e[i] = Math.exp(1);
        }
        upperBound = SPECIES.loopBound(spotPrices.length);
    }
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void testVectorPerformance(Blackhole bh) {
        var upperBound = SPECIES.loopBound(spotPrices.length);
        for (var i=0;i<upperBound; i+= SPECIES.length())
        {
            bh.consume(javaSIMD.calculateBlackScholesSingleCalc(spotPrices,timeToMaturity,strikePrice,
                    interestRate,volatility,e, i));
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    public void testScalarPerformance(Blackhole bh) {
        for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
        {
            bh.consume(javaScalar.calculateBlackScholesSingleCycle(spotPrices,timeToMaturity,strikePrice,
                    interestRate,volatility, i,normDist));
        }
    }
```

```
    public DoubleVector calculateBlackScholesSingleCalc(double[] spotPrices, double[] timeToMaturity, double[] strikePrice,
                                                        double[] interestRate, double[] volatility, double[] e,int i){
...(skip lines)
        DoubleVector vSpot = DoubleVector.fromArray(SPECIES, spotPrices, i);
...(skip lines)
        DoubleVector powerOperand = vRateScaled
                .mul(vTime)
                .neg();
        DoubleVector call  = (vSpot
                .mul(CDFVectorizedExcelOptimized(d1,vE)))
                .sub(vStrike
                .mul(vE
                        .pow(powerOperand))
                .mul(CDFVectorizedExcelOptimized(d2,vE)));
        return call;
```

Here are some JMH benchmarks (2 forks,2 warmups,2 iterations) on a Ryzen 5800X using WSL: Overall, it seems ~2x slower vs the scalar version.  I ran a simple time before vs time after separately, of the method without JMH and it seems inline.

```
Result "blackScholes.TestJavaPerf.testScalarPerformance":
  0.116 ±(99.9%) 0.002 ops/ms [Average]
       89873915287      cycles:u                  #    4.238 GHz                      (40.43%)
      242060738532      instructions:u            #    2.69  insn per cycle   

      
Result "blackScholes.TestJavaPerf.testVectorPerformance":
  0.071 ±(99.9%) 0.001 ops/ms [Average]
       90878787665      cycles:u                  #    4.072 GHz                      (39.25%)
      254117779312      instructions:u            #    2.80  insn per cycle
```

I also enabled diagnostic options for the JVM. I see the following:

```
"-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions", "-XX:+PrintIntrinsics","-XX:+PrintAssembly"
```

```
  0x00007fe451959413:   call   0x00007fe451239f00           ; ImmutableOopMap {rsi=Oop }
                                                            ;*synchronization entry
                                                            ; - jdk.incubator.vector.DoubleVector::arrayAddress@-1 (line 3283)
                                                            ;   {runtime_call counter_overflow Runtime1 stub}
  0x00007fe451959418:   jmp    0x00007fe4519593ce
  0x00007fe45195941a:   movabs $0x7fe4519593ee,%r10         ;   {internal_word}
  0x00007fe451959424:   mov    %r10,0x358(%r15)
  0x00007fe45195942b:   jmp    0x00007fe451193100           ;   {runtime_call SafepointBlob}
  0x00007fe451959430:   nop
  0x00007fe451959431:   nop
  0x00007fe451959432:   mov    0x3d0(%r15),%rax
  0x00007fe451959439:   movq   $0x0,0x3d0(%r15)
  0x00007fe451959444:   movq   $0x0,0x3d8(%r15)
  0x00007fe45195944f:   add    $0x40,%rsp
  0x00007fe451959453:   pop    %rbp
  0x00007fe451959454:   jmp    0x00007fe451231e80           ;   {runtime_call unwind_exception Runtime1 stub}
  0x00007fe451959459:   hlt    
<More halts cut off>   
[Exception Handler]
  0x00007fe451959460:   call   0x00007fe451234580           ;   {no_reloc}
  0x00007fe451959465:   movabs $0x7fe46e76df9a,%rdi         ;   {external_word}
  0x00007fe45195946f:   and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  0x00007fe451959473:   call   0x00007fe46e283d40           ;   {runtime_call}
  0x00007fe451959478:   hlt    
[Deopt Handler Code]
  0x00007fe451959479:   movabs $0x7fe451959479,%r10         ;   {section_word}
  0x00007fe451959483:   push   %r10
  0x00007fe451959485:   jmp    0x00007fe4511923a0           ;   {runtime_call DeoptimizationBlob}
  0x00007fe45195948a:   hlt    
<More halts cut off>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================= C2-compiled nmethod ==============================
  ** svml call failed for double_pow_32
                                            @ 3   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::loadFence (0 bytes)   (intrinsic)
                                            @ 3   jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe::loadFence (0 bytes)   (intrinsic)
                                          @ 2   java.lang.Math::pow (6 bytes)   (intrinsic)
```

Investigations/Questions:

1. Im writing different implementations of the formula, it is not 1:1 - could this be the cause? Looking at the number of instructions according to JMH, there is roughly a 12billion difference in num of instructions. With vectorization the processor runs at a lower clock rate as well.
2. Is the choice of input numbers a problem? I've tried i+10/(array.Length) as well.
3. Is there a reason I see that the SVML call fail for double_pow_32 ? I don't see this problem for smaller input array sizes BTW
4. I changed the pow to mul (for both,obviously the eq is now very different) but it seems to be much faster as a result, results are as expected scalar vs vector

Note: I believe it is using 256bit width vectors (checked during debugging)

Comment: I can just add that I don't see any performance increases at all from using the Vector API, rather the reverse.

Comment: EDIT: for point 4 here are the results
Result "blackScholes.TestJavaPerf.testScalarPerformance":
  0.181 ±(99.9%) 0.020 ops/ms [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (0.177, 0.181, 0.184), stdev = 0.003
  CI (99.9%): [0.161, 0.202] (assumes normal distribution)

Result "blackScholes.TestJavaPerf.testVectorPerformance":
  0.302 ±(99.9%) 0.007 ops/ms [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (0.301, 0.302, 0.304), stdev = 0.001
  CI (99.9%): [0.296, 0.309] (assumes normal distribution)

Comment: @Erik could you clarify instances where you saw regressions with java 17's vector API? sorry just curious

Comment: I did some basic experiments with double arrays of various sizes. I tried out some basic algorithms and basic operations just to see what kind of performance changes would appear. What I saw was consistent performance decrease when using the Vector API.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java's Vector implementation, but if you want to calculate `e^something`, there should also be an `exp(something)` (maybe `something.exp()`) method for that, which should be faster than a generic `pow` implementation. Maybe also something like `exp2`.

Comment: @chtz indeed. While there is no `exp()` method in `DoubleVector`, replacing `vE.pow(powerOperand)` with `powerOperand.lanewise(VectorOperators.EXP)` should do.

Comment: @Holger that worked! 
blackScholes.TestJavaPerf.testScalarPerformance                                        256000  thrpt    4         0.116 ±      0.003     ops/ms


blackScholes.TestJavaPerf.testVectorPerformance                                        256000  thrpt    4         0.237 ±      0.005     ops/ms

So now with vector we're getting roughly double the operations per second of scalar, which is much better than before. Do you want to write the answer so I can mark it as the solution, or should I write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be related to [JDK-8262275, Math vector stubs are not called for double64 vectors](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8262275)

> For Double64Vector, the svml math vector stubs intrinsification is failing and they are not being called from jitted code.
> But we do have svml double64 vectors.

You might try alternative operations, e.g. instead of `vE.pow(powerOperand)` with `vE` being a vector of *e*, you can use `powerOperand.lanewise(VectorOperators.EXP)` to perform *e*<sup>x</sup> for all lanes.

Keep in mind that this API is work in progress in incubator state…